# Google spreadsheets formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

So i am making a sheet to keep track of various statistics about my players in a game of Pathfinder. (Tabletop RPG)

And i'll give and example of how this works, it's very basic.

Any penalty added to P18 will decrease the value in P6 by that amount by use of the following formula: ='Player stats'!H3-P18
(I have the base values for each cell added on another tab.)

In "Ability score modifiers" will numbers also be added, that also have their base values in another tab.

The thing i want happening is that for every 2 i add in cell P18 i want the value in W6 to drop by 1.
So if i added 8 that would drop the value by 4.
And if the value is odd, if possible, i want it do round down. So if P18 was 9, the value in W6 would drop by 4.

Is this possible or am i expecting too much of Google spreadsheets?

[Screenshot battle tracker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTbTz.png)

Comment: Do you add the penalties manually to cell P18?

Comment: Either that or i use =sum(a+b+c+..).

Comment: Did the proposed solution using `rounddown` work for you?

Comment: Yes it did! Sorry, i got all exited when it worked i just kept working and forgot to reply 

Comment: Ok, you should accept it then. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use rounddown(value/2,0).  Refer to screenshot below to see application of following function:

```
=rounddown(c4/2,0)
```

[image: rounddown functioni]

[image: results]

Good luck with you scoring game!